# How to calculate average of a matrix under two conditions using R?

Tags: r, matrix, rows, subscript

I have a big data file named DATA of matrix containing 1200 rows and 19 columns. I would like to calculate the mean of column 16 if the difference between two consecutive rows is 1 sec and if the number of measurements in that given day is more than 50.

Here is what I have tried:

```
N<-length(DATA)
    for (i in 1:N)
    {
    if((DATA[i+1,2]-DATA[i,2])==1&(N>=50)){
    mean<-mean(DATA[,16])}
    }
    mean 

Error in DATA[i + 1, 2] : subscript out of bounds
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is that R?

Comment: Then, it seems that *i+1* is greater than the dimensions of the DATA, one way to solve would be make the loop: `for (i in 1:(N-1))`

Comment: That was my first guess also. However, it give the same type of error message.

Comment: Try setting `N <-dim(DATA)[1]-1`

Comment: Your confusion is that `length` treats your matrix as a vector of length nrows*ncolumns.    However, I can't figure out why you have that `& N>=50` in there, since you know what N is before you start.

Comment: It will be impossible to help you unless you provide more information. Best would be to give an example of your `DATA` and an example of the output you expect.